# Can't run shell script from other shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run a shell script that calls another shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for k in `cat ../config/file1.keywords`
do
  echo "*** keyword: $k ***"
  ./file2.sh $k 
done
```

I got the following error:

```
./file2.sh: Permission denied
```

I tried using: `chmod +x file2.sh`

When I ran my script again, I got a different error:

```
./file2.sh: not found
```

What am I missing here...? Thanks.

(I'm running on a `ubuntu 14.04 LTS` on an `Oracle VM VirtualBox`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you something like `#!/bin/sh` in file2.sh? If not, use `sh file2.sh $k`instead of `./file2.sh $k`

Comment: file2.sh starts with `#!/bin/csh`. I tried removing the `./` as you suggested, but I'm still getting the `not found` error... :(

Comment: Sorry sorry! I removed the `./` but forgot to add the `sh`, as you mentioned. I think it works! Thank you! What is the meaning of adding an `./` in a shell script? I thought it is not usually done this way?

Comment: `./file.sh` means execute file.sh in current directory (and use intepreter from the header)

Comment: So why would removing it and adding `sh` help? I thought you only add `sh` when writing in the terminal... I guess I'm wrong? Sorry about these question, I'm sort of new to this stuff. (and I'll accept your answer soon (the site disables it for the first few minutes), thanks so much!)